# why is **head is used here instead of *head?

Tags: c, linked-list

I know how pointers works.

I done similar problem with this way

```
deleteNode(struct node *head_ref, int key);
```

which is working and @ here http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/ they have used

```
deleteNode(struct node **head_ref, int key);
```

which also correct but is there reason to do so , will 1st one fails in any condition or is it bad way etc.

```
struct linked_list *deleteNode(struct linked_list *head, int key )
{
struct linked_list *prevNode,*current,*temp;

if( head==NULL)
    return head;


if(head->data==key)
{
if(head->next==NULL)

{   free(head);
        return NULL;
}

else 
temp=head->next;

free(head);
return temp;

}
prevNode= head;
current=head->next;


printf("\n %d\n",(current->data));

while((current!=NULL) && (current->data!=key))
{ printf("\n here");

prevNode= current;

current=current->next;
}


if(current==NULL){
    printf("\n element not present in list !\n");
return head;
            }

if(current->next==NULL)

prevNode->next=NULL;


else
prevNode->next=current->next;

free(current);
return head;
}



 head=deleteNode(head,key);
```

Comment: One is a pointer, the other is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: To change an object (from within a function) you need a pointer to it. If the object happens to be a pointer, you'll need a pointer-to-pointer. period.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to delete the head node, the first function won't work because you can't change the head node.  The second function takes the address of the head node so it can be changed if need be.

The `deleteNode` function in the link contains the following:

```
struct node* temp = *head_ref, *prev;

// If head node itself holds the key to be deleted
if (temp != NULL && temp->data == key)
{
    *head_ref = temp->next;   // Changed head
    free(temp);               // free old head
    return;
}
```

You can see here that it dereferences `head_ref` to change what it points to.

Comment: is this correct ?. if am returning new head. (see update)

Answer (score 1):

Let's forget the linked list and just think of updating a variable. There are two, equally valid ways to do it:

```
// 1. pass back
int update_int1(int val) {
  return val + 1;
}

void caller1() {
  int var = 1;
  var = update_int1(var);
}

// 2. write back
void update_int2(int *val) {
  *val += 1;
}

void caller2() {
  int var = 1;
  update_int2(&var);
}
```

This is easy to understand, so let's do the same thing with a pointer:

```
// 1. pass back
char *update_ptr1(char *ptr) {
  return ptr + 1;
}

void caller1() {
  char *ptr = malloc(10);
  ptr = update_ptr1(ptr);
}

// 2. write back
void update_ptr2(char **ptr) {
  *ptr += 1;
}

void caller2() {
  char *ptr = malloc(10);
  update_ptr2(&ptr);
}
```

It works exactly the same as for `int`! The key is there's always *one more* star if you want to write back, not pass back.

Which pattern you choose is up to you. The write-back approach is popular for linked lists.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When you write *b==>access contents of address contained in b.

When you write **c==>Access contents of contents of address contained in c.